# Formal justification of "$d$" in $z=re^{i\theta}\implies dz=e^{i\theta}\,dr+ire^{i\theta}\,d\theta$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

According to Wikipedia:

$$z=re^{i\theta}\\\implies dz=e^{i\theta}\,dr+ire^{i\theta}\,d\theta\tag{1}$$

Now I kind of get this - the following is definitely rigorous:

$$\partial_r z=e^{i\theta}\\\partial_\theta z=i\cdot re^{i\theta}\\\tag{2}$$

So $(1)$ seems well-justified, in a loose sort of way. However:

$$z=\int\,dz$$

And:

$$\int e^{i\theta}\,dr+\int ire^{i\theta}\,d\theta=re^{i\theta}+re^{i\theta}=2z$$

Which makes me strongly doubt that $(1)$ is true, when integrating both sides finds a contradiction - although I of course trust that Wikipedia is correct, but I just don’t see how. What's going on?

P.S. I’ve seen it written many times that the (Leibniz?) “$d$” notation is often used unrigorously, and perhaps I am misunderstanding what the $d$ operator is actually saying... what’s more formal?

Comment: What does the integral  mean? The Wikipedia result is true as equality of one forms but one need to specify the one cycle to integra against for the rest

Comment: Well, if $(1)$ holds, then: $$z=\int 1\cdot\,dz=\int(e^{i\theta}\,dr+i\cdot re^{i\theta}\,d\theta)$$ Surely? Clearly this is wrong but I’m unsure why. It’s still wrong even if you consider definite integrals

Comment: Again what does the integral  mean? In the plane you got specify a one cycle (eg path) to integrate on

Comment: I’ve heard of differential forms and one-forms before, but what’s a cycle? As I understand it, the integral is the limit of Riemann sums (or a Lebesgue integration) which require a $d$ element and Wikipedia certainly uses those “one forms” in an integration to prove the formula for winding numbers... @Conrad

Comment: Oh! So you’re saying if I specified a line integral, then the integral of the LHS *would* equal the RHS, right? @Conrad

Comment: A cycle is a formal sum of paths with coefficients  - do not confuse the situation  here with the one dimensional  case where there is essentially  only one path

Comment: Yes - the symbol integral  of $dz$ doesn't  make make sense otherwise  as opposed to the real case when it has a default sense

Comment: @Conrad Which justifies Wikipedia’s use of the equality in the line integrals for winding numbers? Thank you!

Comment: Yes - to visualize better think of a circular arc centered at the origin where $dr=0$ so the integral is only in theta or conversely a segment on a half line through the origin where $d\theta=0$ and the integral  is only in $r$

Comment: @Conrad I'm sure we agree on the maths, but from a pedagogic perspective I'd formulate the conclusion as: The formula conjectured by the OP makes perfect sense, as long as $dz$ is treated as $\frac{dz(r(t),\theta(t))}{dt}dt$ (and the same with $z$ replaced by $\theta$ or $r$) and as long as one is aware that the equality has an implied placeholder over all paths $\mathbb{R}\ni t\mapsto (r(t), \theta(t))\in \mathbb{R}^2$ . The only error made by the OP is therefore that when evaluating $\int e^{i\theta} dr$ they treated $\theta$ as a constant. I think talking about cycles only adds confusion

Comment: It still doesn't quite click for me @Bananach. Without delving into the theory of differential forms, how might I show rigorously (or at least strongly justify) the equality? For example, if my classmate asked me what I was writing, at the moment I'd have no response to give to them... other than a heuristic one

Comment: In general even, if $f(c_1,c_2,c_3,\cdots,c_n)$ is an $n$-variable function, how do I show that $df=\partial_{c_1}f\,dc_1+\partial_{c_2}f\,d_{c_2}+\cdots+\partial_{c_n}f\,dc_n$?

Comment: It is not correct to split up the integral: $\int (e^{i\theta} dr+ire^{i\theta}d\theta)\neq \int e^{i\theta}dr+\int ire^{i\theta}d\theta$, just like in calculus of real variables, this is a line integral

Comment: @Sal oh, I didn't realize the OP could have meant a complex integral. FShrike, did you? In that cases things are a bit different. If not, your $df=..$ in the last comment is simply the infinitesimal form of the same equality with $d$ replaced by $\Delta$, and to make things rigorous without differential forms, you can divide by $dt$